# Logged In or Not check works only in Customer pages not other pages Magento 2

Tags: magento2, module, session, helper, user

User logged in or not checking not works in other pages such as Product, Category and other static pages but its works well on customer pages like Dashboard, Address book, Orders etc...

**Here is my helper:** *app/code/MyVendor/MyUserModule/Helper/Data.php*

```
<?php 
        namespace MyVendor\MyUserModule\Helper;
        class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
        {

            public function __construct(
                \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
                \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
            ) {
                $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
                parent::__construct($context);
            }

            public function isLoggedIn()
            {
                return $this->customerSession->isLoggedIn();
            }
            public function userLoggedDetails()
            {
                return $this->customerSession->getCustomer();
            }
        }
?>
```

**And phtml like this**

```
<?php 
    $customerSession = $this->helper('MyVendor\MyUserModule\Helper\Data');
    if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
        echo "Welcome ".$customerSession->userLoggedDetails()->getName();
    }else{
        echo "Login";
    }
?>
```

Also I noticed logged in or not checking works well on all pages while call  **ObjectManager** directly, like this way

```
$om = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerSession = $om->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
```

but this method not recommended by experts, so should follow Constructor injecting proper method, Anyone know what I missed, please.

Comment: If you enable full page cache, it stills working well?

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh I already enabled all caches from admin, is any other cache place have to enable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I got the answer, the problem with block cache, to get real Magento session, specific block cache must be false!

I did following changes and worked well:

1. Added `$this->_isScopePrivate = true;` in my __construct
2. Added attribute `cacheable="false"` to my block which belongs-to my template .phtml

Comment: Where you add the `cacheable="false"` ? I have same issue with Magento 2.1 but I do not know where to add attribute and how should look complete file.

Comment: @GeorgeGeorge add cacheable="false" in your layout xml for the curresponding block.

In my case on this file, `/app/design/frontend/My_vendor/my_theme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml`
I have to add this block `<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="usermenu.us.li" template="Magento_Theme::html/user_nav_us_li.phtml" before="-" cacheable="false"/>`